# Share additional namespace imports in LINQPad with a team

Tags: linqpad

When I add Additional References to the "My Extensions" script in LINQPad these are available for all new queries, which is really handy for sharing them with other people. Is there a way to similarly share the default Additional Namespace Imports for new queries? I know I can click "Set as default for new queries", but that only saves them for me. (Where does this store them, anyway?)

Comment: Is the Additional Namespaces not included in the linq file you are sharing?

Comment: They are, but I want to share the default imports for new queries. Edited the question to clarify this.

Comment: take a look at `%AppData%\LINQPad\DefaultQuery.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default namespaces for new queries are stored in `%AppData%\LINQPad\DefaultQuery.xml`

As of v5.06.02, LINQPad lets you copy/move this file into the LINQPad.exe directory, and if present, it will take precedence over the copy in `%AppData%\LINQPad`.

This means you can now share default namespaces with a team, as long as you run LINQPad.exe from the same shared folder. You can share other data in a similar manner, including [queries, drivers, plug-ins, connections and default references](https://www.linqpad.net/PortableDeployment.aspx).